# I'd like to ask about a new tool for an old workflow problem, is this a good question for Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, specific-question, old-questions

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: *[Can I improve my workflow for PRs with the GitHub CLI tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69802618/is-github-cli-tool-change-workflow-for-pr)*

I found a good older question about Git's workflow with [PRs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_version_control#Pull_requests) and I want to know what's different about it in 2021. My rep score doesn't give me the ability to leave comments, so I posted my question instead. So far I've been downvoted... do I have other options?

Comment: Wait... I thought you needed 5 rep to use meta... I must have misunderstood

Comment: Related: *[Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/)*

Answer (score 12):

You can ask it as it is about a tool commonly used by programmers, but as currently worded, it is in an unacceptable state.

Firstly, Stack Overflow is not a forum: there is no place for meta-information of what you are about to do "if needed" — every post should be **self-contained** at the time it is posted, not some time afterward.

Secondly, "can I improve my workflow" is not a good title for a question. Contrary to popular belief, we are not a free help center or, again, a technology forum, we are Wikipedia for programmers — please treat the service accordingly. A given post should be useful to **future readers**.

Thirdly, focus on the exact problem you are trying to solve (and no, "improving workflow" is not a problem, but something like "how to edit someone's PR using GitHub CLI" is).

Finally, regarding the "doesn't give me the ability to leave comments" - see point #2, this is one of the reasons comments on posts of *others* are locked behind a reputation threshold: we are not a forum, and thus pestering others about a related problem is not an acceptable way of approaching things either.

The system nudged you to do exactly what we are supposed to be doing - asking questions and answering them. However, asking a *good* question is *hard*, and we get [*literally* several thousands of questions every given day](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday), so please be mindful of the limited volunteers' time.

You asked a question, so the ball is now in your court - you need to **edit it into shape**.

Answer (score 2):

> "I found a good older question about git's workflow with PRs and I
> want to know what's different about it in 2021".

Yet that is not what you are actually asking! You are instead asking a question which really begs for the flippant response "I don't know, can you?". In fact one of the comments you got is pretty much a nicer version of it.

The question body pretty much not clearly stating what you want to know is a red flag and a sign that you need to rewrite it. But do you know what is even a bigger red flag?

Your question ending with the footnote

> If needed, I can rephrase my question to fully reflect the content of the 2014 question.

I can rewrite that as "My gut is telling me I'm not explaining myself well enough". If that happens, don't just go ahead anyway and see where you end up. Take your time and rewrite the question until you are fully satisfied with it. If you can't get it to a state where you are satisfied with it, that is another red flag - one indicating that you are not ready to ask the question yet on Stack Overflow.

Because first you need to do some research; what has changed in a tool... that is usually well-documented. If you don't want to go as far as going through a history of changes, you can at least read the current up to date documentation of the tool to see for yourself what its broad features are, and probably spot some new ones in there yourself.

For sure that will take some time if there have been a lot of releases of said tool, but Stack Overflow does not exist so you can make other people spend their time so you don't have to spend yours. I invite you to put the mouse on the downvote button so you can see the tooltip that will appear, explaining when you would downvote a question. A lack of research is very much at the heart of it.